# presentViewController does not hide popover, popover appears on presented modal view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uipopovercontroller, presentviewcontroller

I'm facing this weird issue where i present a popover from a button on a view. Later i call presentViewController, without dismissing the popover. View is presented modally. Weird thing is, modal view does not cover the popover, popover appears on top of modal view. I'm on iPad Retina, iOS 7.1. In the attached image, purple view is modal view and blue one is the popover. Please help if someone had been through pain and resolved it. Thanks in advance.

Code to present popover -

```
[self.pop presentPopoverFromRect:[sender frame]
                 inView:[self.navigationController view]
                    permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                    animated:YES];
```

Code to present modal view -

```
[self presentViewController:anotherVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

[image]

Comment: Dismiss your popover before presenting new viewController.

Comment: Does not resolve the issue, i need this popover in place once modal view is dismissed. Also, this is not an ideal solution, it's a workaround. Any modally presented view should be hiding all views of the parent caller.

Answer (score 0):

The offending line seems to be [self.navigationController view]. Why not do self.view? Or if that line is a must, do [self.navigationController presentViewController...

Comment: Nice observation. Had already tried by replacing  [self.navigationController view] with [self view] and [self.navigationController presentViewController . Does not work. Same result.

Comment: Hmm bummer. Looks like you will have to use "dismissPopoverAnimated" to dismiss it before you are presenting the new view controller

Comment: i need this popover in place once modal view is dismissed. Also, this is not an ideal solution, it's a workaround. Any modally presented view should be hiding all views of the parent caller.

Answer (score 0):

The API said this "The popover remains visible until the user taps outside of the popover window or you explicitly dismiss it.". If you use the UIPopoverController I think there no way to solve this.

[UIPopoverController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverController_class/index.html)

Comment: i need this popover in place once modal view is dismissed.  Any modally presented view should be hiding all views of the parent caller.

Comment: I agree but I'm not sure where the problem lies. Worse case you can redisplay the popup as the modal dismisses

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this. Rather than calling presentViewCOntroller, i say

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.view duration:0.5
    options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom 
    animations:^ { [self.view addSubview:anotherVC]; }
    completion:nil];
```